# Solving $\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{\bar{z}+z}{z^2+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I know that $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\bar{z}}{z}$ and $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{|z|}{z}$  don't exist.
    I know also that $\lim_{z \to\infty} \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}=0$ when $\mathrm{deg}(P)<\mathrm{deg}(Q)$, but $\bar{z}+z$ is not a polynomial in $z$.
    I also know basic properties of limits of complex functions, like turning an infinite limit into a finite limit.
I don't know how to approach this limit seriously.
    Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|z|>1\implies\left|\frac{\overline z+z}{z^2+1}\right|\leqslant\frac{2|z|}{|z|^2-1}$,$$\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{\overline z+z}{z^2+1}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that $z = M e^{i\theta}$, and $\overline{z} = M e^{-i\theta}$. Then:

$$\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{\bar{z}+z}{z^2+1} = \lim_{M \to \infty} \frac{M e^{-i\theta}+M e^{i\theta}}{M^2 e^{i2\theta} + 1} =
\lim_{M \to \infty} \frac{M\left( e^{-i\theta}+e^{i\theta}\right)}{M^2\left( e^{i2\theta} + \frac{1}{M^2}\right)} = 0.$$

Comment: You have shown that the function tends to zero on all rays of the origin. I don't see why (or even believe that) this suffices in general, so I would not advise to use this method.

Comment: For a counterexample, consider the function which maps $ z=Me^{i\theta} $ to $ 0 $ if $ \theta=0 $ and to $ \frac{1}{M\theta} $ if $ \theta \in ]0,2\pi[ $.

Comment: Perhaps for continuous functions your argument works, but then again it is not trivial why.